# Find $x$ for inequality of $1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+...+x^{99}\le0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Finding the range of $x$ for inequality of $1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+...+x^{99}\le0$

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We observe that $x=1$ is not a solution. Now note that $1+x+...+x^{99}=\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x}$ (show this!), so that the inequality becomes $\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x}\ge 0$. From here we observe if $x>1$, the bottom part is negative. We also have the case $x<1$. These you should be able to do.

Good luck!

Comment: He didn't include $x^1$ in the sum

Comment: Sorry, I've change the inequality sometimes..

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that was the question. I wrote a new solution, but then rollback after OP edited.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stack-exchange!